# Understanding the useState hook behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently in the process of implementing a ripple effect in my application. I'm using the Material UI Button (https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/) as a starting point for this.

During my own implementation I've run into some behaviour I'm unsure about. I've created a corresponding sandbox with a basic example, https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cloud-69uvh?file=/src/App.js.

The `Container` is the Parent Component and the `Ripple` is the Child Component. The `Container` has a `onMouseUp` and `onMouseDown` handler, which adds and removes the child component respectively.

Below is a small extract of the `onMouseDown` logic. The `rippleCounter` variable is a ref object that keeps a count which is used to set the `key` of the `Ripple`.

```
    setRipples((oldRipples) => {
      return [
        ...oldRipples,
        <Ripple
          key={rippleCounter.current}
          timeout={500}
          rippleX={rippleX}
          rippleY={rippleY}
          rippleSize={rippleSize}
        />
      ];
    });
    rippleCounter.current += 1;
  };
```

I understand that `useState` is asynchronous, so there is no guarantee that the `key` set against the `Ripple` component will be before or after it is incremented. This is where I'm having some difficulties understanding.

Example 2 follows this asynchronous behaviour, as the `Ripple` component is having its `key` value set either before or after. This results in the ripple being messed up as the same key is implemented in some cases.

Example 1 doesn't appear to follow this behaviour. The `setRipples` function is always run in an synchronous fashion, with `rippleCounter` always being incremented after the `setRipples` function is run. i.e. Same key is never useed.

**Example 1**
State being managed and updated before child component is removed.

```
const Ripple = ({
  in: inProp,
  onExited = () => {},
  timeout,
  rippleSize,
  rippleY,
  rippleX
}) => {
  const [leaving, setLeaving] = useState(false);

  const style = {
    width: rippleSize,
    height: rippleSize,
    top: -(rippleSize / 2) + rippleY,
    left: -(rippleSize / 2) + rippleX
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!inProp) {
      setLeaving(true);

      const timeoutValue = setTimeout(onExited, timeout);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutValue);
      };
    }
  }, [timeout, inProp, onExited]);

  return (
    <span style={style} className="ripple">
      <span className={"ripple-child" + (leaving ? " leaving" : "")}></span>
    </span>
  );
};
```

**Example 2**
No state being managed.

```
const Ripple = ({
  in: inProp,
  onExited = () => {},
  timeout,
  rippleSize,
  rippleY,
  rippleX
}) => {
  // const [leaving, setLeaving] = useState(false);

  const style = {
    width: rippleSize,
    height: rippleSize,
    top: -(rippleSize / 2) + rippleY,
    left: -(rippleSize / 2) + rippleX
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!inProp) {
      // setLeaving(true);

      const timeoutValue = setTimeout(onExited, timeout);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutValue);
      };
    }
  }, [timeout, inProp, onExited]);

  return (
    <span style={style} className="ripple">
      <span className={"ripple-child" + (!inProp ? " leaving" : "")}></span>
    </span>
  );
};
```

Apologies for the poor articulation. If there is additional information I can provide, please let me know.